# Как протестировать обработку входящего смс в android приложении на эмуляторе?

Tags: java, android, тестирование

Есть **receiver**, который принимает входящие смс, проверяет, если смс пришло с одного из номеров из списка, то тогда разбирает текст сообщения по регулярному выражению и вытаскивает код из сообщения:

```
package com.ragmon.jokes.receivers;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;

import com.ragmon.jokes.services.SmsService;

public class SMSMonitor extends BroadcastReceiver {
private static final String ACTION = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

private static final String[] fromList = new String[]{
        "+380934542433"
};

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent != null && intent.getAction() != null &&
            ACTION.compareToIgnoreCase(intent.getAction()) == 0) {

        Object[] pduArray = (Object[]) intent.getExtras().get("pdus");
        SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pduArray.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < pduArray.length; i++) {
            messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pduArray[i]);
        }

        String sms_from = messages[0].getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
        if (isSmsFromServiceNumber(sms_from)) {
            StringBuilder bodyText = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                bodyText.append(messages[i].getMessageBody());
            }

            String body = bodyText.toString();
            Intent mIntent = new Intent(context, SmsService.class);
            mIntent.putExtra("sms_body", body);
            context.startService(mIntent);

            abortBroadcast();
        }
    }
}

private boolean isSmsFromServiceNumber(String serviceNumber) {
    for (String from : fromList) {
        if (from.equalsIgnoreCase(serviceNumber))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

Далее запускает **service** и обрывает цепочку **receivers** `abortBroadcast();` (чтобы сообщение не попало в журнал входящих смс устройства).
В дальнейшем работа с кодом из смс производится в **service**:

```
package com.ragmon.jokes.services;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.util.Log;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class SmsService extends Service {

    private static final String URL = "http://google.com/";

    private static final String smsTo = "+380934542364";

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        final String sms_body = intent.getExtras().getString("sms_body");
        final String code = getSmsCode(sms_body);

        sendToUrl(URL, code, new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                sendSms(smsTo, code);
            }
        });

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    private void sendToUrl(String url, String code, Runnable onError) {
        url = url + "?code=" + code;

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget= new HttpGet(url);

        HttpResponse response = null;
        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200){
                throw new Exception("HTTP Status != 200");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("SmsService", "Can\'t send http request.");
            onError.run();
        }
    }

    private void sendSms(String to, String code) {
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(to, null, code, null, null);
    }

    private String getSmsCode(String sms_body) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)");
        if (pattern.matcher(sms_body).matches()) {
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sms_body);
            matcher.find();

            return matcher.group(1);
        }
        return null;
    }


}
```

В **service** производится попытка отправить код из сообщения по URL. Если произошла какая-то ошибка при отправки кода на URL, то тогда отправляется смс содержащее код на номер телефона.

Подскажите,
как можно при помощи эмулятора + adb (возможно посоветуете другой способ, без использования реального устройства) произвести симуляцию входящего сообщения, чтобы протестировать этот функционал?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Использую Android Studio 2.2.2 и дефолтный Android Virtual Device Manager(AVD Manager).

В нём прекрасно тестируются и смс и входящие звонки и GPS.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- кликайте на кнопку "More" (троеточие) в панели рядом с эмулятором
- появится окно с доп.возможностями
- выбираете вкладку Phone
- выбираете номер телефона с которого выполнить звонок или отправить сообщение
- заполняете текст сообщения кликаете на кнопку Send